# Add Javascript array to form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I am building a group mailing system with VueJS and jQuery for the front-end, Laravel 5 for the back-end.

I am using AJAX calls to retrieve a listing of users based on groups, agencies, or all active users. The user may then remove addresses based on these results in the DOM (VueJS `data`) and manually add new addresses.

The form includes a file so I cannot (or do not want to, based on compatibility concerns) send the form data using an AJAX call. The problem is that I need to send the listing of email addresses along with the form when the user submits it.

Here is the Javascript. The most relevant part is the `serializeRecipients` method where I append each email address to hidden form fields:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#emailContainer',
    data: {
        recipients: [
            {
               name: "Joe Smith",
               email: "joe@demo.com"
            }
        ],
        individualRecipients: [],
        manualRecipient: null,
        validation: {
            email: true
        }
    },

    methods: {
        //
        serializeRecipients: function() {
            var recipientAddresses = [];
            var individualRecipientAddresses = [];
            $.each(this.recipients, function (k, recipient) {
                recipientAddresses.push(recipient['email']);
            });
            $.each(this.individualRecipients, function(k, recipient) {
                individualRecipientAddresses.push(recipient);
            });

            $("#recipientsInput").val(recipientAddresses);
            $("#individualRecipientsInput").val(individualRecipientAddresses);
        }
    }
});
```

On the form element I use `v-on="submit: serializeRecipients"`. This generates this form output: `someone@demo.com, someoneelse@demo.com`, which I am then using PHP's `explode()` function to transform into an array.

This all works but I'm left wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just join the array into a string and then parse it on the server.

```
$("#recipientsInput").val(recipientAddresses.join(','));
$("#individualRecipientsInput").val(individualRecipientAddresses.join(','));
```

So:

```
['me@somewhere.com', 'you@somewhereelse.com', 'him@somewhere.com']
```

Would become:

```
'me@somewhere.com,you@somewhereelse.com,him@somewhere.com'
```

Then on the server you could split up that field by commas.

Comment: I'm already getting a comma separated value with the code I have so far. The `recipientAddresses` array consists of objects, so I need the `email` property. However, `individualRecipientAddresses` is just a plain array, so I like your suggestion for that - less code.

Comment: Gotcha, sorry. I must have skimmed the last paragraph of your question. I think what you're doing is pretty standard. I'm not sure there is a *better* way.

Comment: Sorry about that, should have added an object to that array to make it more clear (edited). This could have about a hundred recipients (or more), think this approach is still okay? Really can't think of other options without being able to use AJAX..

Comment: Yeah I mean, if you can't post to the server with AJAX or over a websocket then it's gotta make it up there somehow right? The only other way I could think of is to dynamically add input elements to your form for each address, but that would be more code and probably even less performant. So yeah, I think a couple hundred addresses in a single field won't hurt. Hell, ASP.NET Web Forms uses a hidden form field to track view state and that sucker gets so large that Chrome lags when you view source on some of those sites :P

Comment: @NightMICU, totally understand if this answer didn't end up being your solution, but if it did then don't forget to accept it ;)

Comment: I'm on the fence lol. I had already accomplished getting the data the way you presented, I guess I was either looking for validation that I was doing this correctly or a better approach to sending the data with the form. Could you tweak your answer a bit to include more than how to get a CSV (of sorts) value?

Comment: I'm not sure what you would like me to add lol. I thought you were asking if there's a better way and I confirmed that you're doing it an acceptable way. I don't think you'll find too many more succinct options, but maybe you will.